# MDX SSAS query issue with Linkmember and filter 2 date timensions

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to compute the aggregate of Opportunities Count that are active at a time (which is defined by period between start date and closing date) Not just for that period but for over all...

Opportunities Count for 2016 should include the sum of opportunities from NULL : 2015 and those that are closed in 2016:NULL.

Same thing for month and year

I have the following query that works but is giving me incorrect results for quarter, Month, date level. But gives the correct results for Year. I guess it is because of non unique key names in both dimensions

```
with member [Measures].[cumulative_count]
as 

aggregate({NULL:[Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].currentmember.lag(1) } *
{LINKMEMBER([Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].currentmember.lead(1),[Opportuntity Close Dt].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date]):NULL}
,[Measures].[Opportunities Count])

SELECT [Measures].[cumulative_count] on columns,
[Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].[Month].members on rows 
from 

AdventCube
```

I guess I am running into an issue with ALL member as specified in the link

http://richardlees.blogspot.com/2011/06/linkmember.html

But to override the ALL member I am running into syntax errors. Could anyone please help?

Comment: No all member needed here. Check output of [Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].currentmember.lag(1).UniqueName and LINKMEMBER([Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].currentmember.lead(1),[Opportuntity Close Dt].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date]).UniqueName. It should make things clear to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get little bit of visibility into the members using uniquename.

For both Quarter and Month the membername is the same. I think that is where the problem is.
For example for 2016 both Quarter and Month show the same date when Linkmember is used. 
Quarter 1 : [Opportunity Close Dt].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].[Quarter].&[2]&[2016]
January : [Opportunity Close Dt].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].[Date].&[2016-01-02T00:00:00]


Any ideas on how to fix this??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get what to fix. Can you state "it returns that, but should return this"?